# Decoding Game data

Tags: decryption, encodings

I am very new to this whole business so please bear with me.

Goal: Am trying to decode data from a post request from game to server starting with Q0.
Most of the game data is encoded in Base64, but the data i'm looking for seems to have another layer of encryption/decoding

So far i've played around with Burp Suite, various online decoders, but no luck yet.
if anyone recognises this format, please advise how to decrypt/decode it.
Thank you very much!

Example:
`Q0NaIQAAAAIAAAAAAAADBXicbVE9SwNBFNzNfiWBcM2hGFJbKFhpk8ITC0Es/AZjI9YpLAQVYqNFAvkFYiAJdmIKUTBYWFmIgsHGKhYqBCxsg1Zq5jbvuGAWFvbNvJmdt7vO7Ip3tlOaPTSSR2JaxdXKfat8kTqrLXlyvNicPtnM/FaT1dw773KowaEHvOW4AAc86JcWQx+wx+HtOldK4gxsJJ1KgA/j0PfgXju9ZyRjiktXtX92m2B3no5vyaWVaSS4riznjWBMCsEjXuHzAexHazTPuzUUVMMBStTMnC80TAdUQkaDZOhGgvAUlM5ijnKu51779k9NFJ+RJaqVq9ABBh30XpcV95TmDXMW5wJ4D9a9DRj9CXTZ8swiXoWSUArM53Md L9IFmFed3EA6zW7mj2o4xaLa+lMWmiq3/zbG1dA/f9zvc9L601z+f2k38CINOP9u7fR4kc5mdftmsLq4yjbXvsM45vEzaKW+kqtZ+NCc4P0sg4WrAxNhTLCtl1IdJ8kGxF3NcGD++gNkSTkw`

Comment: Unless you get really lucky and it's a protobuf (and [this decoder](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) doesn't decode it) etc. it's very difficult to pull apart some arbitrary binary data without any context. You might do better reverse engineering the part of the code that assembles this.

Comment: is the example string  complete? (537 char)